# Is it possible to get the Download-Source/App-Store of a APK?

Tags: android, download, installation, apk, analytics

We're experiencing installations from our app which aren't related to the Google Play Store Downloads in China.

So the management came up with the question if it's possible to track the Store down which provides our APK. I know that this is almost impossible because the signed APK has no data which is related to the store.

But maybe I'm wrong. So is there any information of the store from where the APK is installed on a phone?

Comment: I don't know if you can track your app installation, but maybe using Google-Analytics and help you tracking the user from where.

Comment: I know that the users are from China.